# How to decrease and increase values as a curve

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I am trying to do a digging tool for my game, I have x and y coordinates of point A and B, what I want to do is create a curve between these points, nothing graphical I just need loop through the coordinates (float x, float y).

I am not good at explaining so here is a visual example;

[image: Example]

The first image is what's happen if I just use a for loop to decrease the y value until middle and then increase it from the middle to end.

```
//Very specific code for my example 
//I wrote it just for this example so I am not sure if it works

float y;
float x;

public void Example(float startX, float endX, float startY, float endY, float depth)
{
    y = startY;
    x = startX;
    float changeAmountOfY = depth / (endX - startX);

    for (int i = (int)startX; i < (startX + endX) / 2; i++)
    {
        x++;
        y -= changeAmountOfY; 
    }

    for (int i = (int)(startX + endX) / 2; i < endX; i++)
    {
        x++;
        y += changeAmountOfY;
    }
}

public void ChangeCoordinates()
{
    Example(100f, 200f, 100f, 100f, 50f);
}
```

The second image is what I need.

> I am developing the game on unity and I am using Vector2 for the coordinates but it is not important. 
> Pure C# or even C++ is welcome. 
> It is also fine if someone can just explain the math behind what I am trying to do.

Comment: You have a 1/2 circle with radius 50 and center (150,100)

Comment: The problem with your example is that it doesn 't actually draw anything as far as I understand... However I seee the idea. For creating a "semi-circle" (that's what your "curve" looks like), you'd be better of imagining you loop over a small angle change between -180° and 0° (are you familiar with trigonometry?). The "change of x" and "change of y" would be very simple to express in terms of trigonometric operations (sine and cosine). If I'm not mistaken, for an angle, small change of x would be `-sin(alpha)*radius` and change of y would be `cos(alpha)*radius`

Comment: To do something like your example that would mean a single loop `int radius=50;   y = startY;
    x = startX; for (int alpha = -180; alpha < 0; alpha++) { x += -Mathf.Sin(alpha)*radius; y += Mathf.Cos(alpha)*radius; }`. I hop I got my trig and my differential calculs right... **important** I assume `cos` and `sin` actually use degrees, not radians.

Comment: Since unity3d uses radians apparently, You need to change "-180" to `-Mathf.PI`, and change `alpha++` to a smaller increment like `alpha += Mathf.PI / 100`

Comment: Now, you could first test this in your situation for the example coordinates, and the question now is how you want to be generalized exactly? Surely you don't want any imaginable parameters for your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```cs
// Calculate radius
int radius = (B.X - A.X) / 2;

// Calculate middle
int middle_x = A.X + radius;
int middle_y = A.Y;
// or
int middle_y = (A.Y + B.Y) / 2;


// Coordinates for a semicircle
// 0 to 180 degree
for (int i = 0; i <= 180; i++)
{
  double x_coordinate = middle_x + radius * Math.Cos(i * Math.PI / 180);

  // Opened to bottom
  double y_coordinate = middle_y + radius * Math.Sin(i * Math.PI / 180);

  // or opened to top
  double y_coordinate = middle_y - radius * Math.Sin(i * Math.PI / 180);
}
```

Take a look at [unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle).